# How to redirect user to edit page after creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm a little bit confused - when user creation is successful.

I can call ( working )

```
if @wibiya_user.save
 render :edit
end
```

but why when I write

```
   if @wibiya_user.save
       format.html { redirect_to edit_wibiya_user_path(@wibiya_user) }
   end
```

I get Routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"wibiya_users"}
```

However I do have in my routes:

```
     resources :wibiya_users
 ...
rake routes
  edit_wibiya_user GET    /wibiya_users/:id/edit(.:format) wibiya_users#edit
```

Why it is happening like that ?

Comment: It shouldn't  - can you show us your complete action from where you redirect, and all routes concerning the `:wibiya_users` resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your users controller (filename, class name, redirects, etc.) to be a WibiyaUsersController.

Explanation:  The `resources :wilibya_user` in your `routes.rb` file sets up the various routes for that resource.  It assumes the controller is called `wibiya_users_controller`

Comment: Thanks) Can you help me with this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329960/how-i-can-dynamically-generate-url-for-generating-xls-report or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328873/how-to-check-user-email-uniqueness-and-pass-result-to-jquery